# What are the benefits of direct sun viewing spectrometer over a backscatter measuring spectrometer to quantify trace gases in the atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-chemistry, air-pollution

I am using a Pandora spectrometer and a MAX-DOAS spectrometer to quantify the amount of formaldehyde (HCHO) present in the troposphere and stratosphere in Fairbanks, Alaska. Both the spectrometers use the Lambert-Beer's law for quantifying the amount of HCHO in the air by using different viewing geometries. I want to know what role does the view geometry play in the working of these spectrometers.

[image]

Comment: May be a better fit for astronomy stack exchange?

Comment: @gimelist the question is about methods for measuring the composition of the earth's atmosphere. I guess Chemistry might be relevant, but why on earth astronomy?

Comment: I believe the Earth Sciences is an interdisciplinary science, and in fact the answer that I have written is mostly inspired by the input I got from Physics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I deleted your answer because it was plagiarised, copied without attribution from [this answer on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/415387/6319).  Feel free to add your own answer in your own words, or to properly quote and attribute an answer you've found elsewhere.